# smooth differential forms on manifold with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms, topological-groups, geometric-topology

What is the definition of smooth differential forms on smooth manifold with boundary? Could someone please provide an example?

Comment: What are smooth differential forms on $\Bbb H^k = \{(x_1,\dots,x_k)\in\Bbb R^k: x_k\ge 0\}$?

Comment: Thanks. Yes,  What are they?

Comment: What are smooth functions on $\Bbb H^k$?

Comment: A smooth function can refer to a function that is infinitely differentiable. More generally, it refers to a function having continuous derivatives.

Comment: You have not addressed the key issue. I’m not debating what “smooth” means, but asking how you deal with the domain at hand.

Comment: A function on an open subset of ℍⁿ is smooth if it is the restriction of a smooth function on an open subset of ℝⁿ.